# Replace last character in a large file

Tags: perl

I have a program that pulls data from a number of other files to form a large (~200MB) bulk SQL insert statement

```
INSERT INTO ...
VALUES
('a','b',1,2,3),
('c','d',4,5,6),
```

Unfortunately, the last line needs to end on a semicolon instead of a comma. Is there a way to (ideally within my perl program) turn only the very last character from a `,` into a `;`?

Things I've tried:

1) After the file has been finished and closed:

```
open(DAT,">>$output") || die("Cannot Open File");
seek(DAT, 2, SEEK_END); 
print DAT ";"; 
close(DAT);
```

This just puts a semicolon at the very end.

2) Calling `` `perl -p -i -e 's/,$/;/g' $output`; `` from within my perl program, but this is replacing every comma.

3) While printing the last line, end with a semicolon instead of a comma. This doesn't work however because I don't actually know it was the last line until the line has been written.

4) Copy the whole file into a new file, except the last character is a `;` instead of a `,`. This is slow however, and thus not ideal.

Comment: Are you opposed to CPAN modules?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. It's running on an external server with pretty tight install restrictions. Not sure which modules will be available.

Not the best environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that the ',' you are replacing is always going to be the second last byte in the file (last byte being a "\n"), then you can try this:

```
my $fsize = -s $filename;  
# print $fsize."\n";
open($FILE, "+<", $filename) or die $!; 
seek $FILE, $fsize-2, SEEK_SET; # or 0 (numeric) instead of SEEK_SET
print $FILE ";";
close $FILE;
```

Comment: Works great except that it gives the warning `Argument "SEEK_SET" isn't numeric in seek at app.pl line 55.`

Long as it works, though, I'm happy.

Comment: @AlexQueue you can replace SEEK_SET with the number 0.

Comment: @AlexQueue or add a `use Fcntl;` to import that definition. Or use 2 (or SEEK_END) and a negative position, then you don't need to capture the file size before.

Answer (score 1):

You tried

```
perl -p -i -e 's/,$/;/g'
```

Which will apply this replacement on every line in the file. To only do it once, slurp the file using the `-0` switch:

```
perl -0777 -pi -e 's/,$/;/'
```

This will only match if the last character is a comma (with optional trailing newline). If you have trailing whitespace or other characters, it will not work.

Comment: This works great from the terminal but not from within my Perl program. Not a huge problem, but it means the accepted answer was a little bit easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You use wron offset. SEEK_END adds(!) the offset to the END position. So use "-2" as an offset. Try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, "+<x.txt" or die;
seek $fh, -2, 2;
print $fh ";\n";
close $fh;
```

Or a little bit more talkative:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Fcntl qw(SEEK_END);

open my $fh, "+<x.txt" or die;
seek $fh, -2, SEEK_END;
print $fh ";\n";
close $fh;
```